# how to fill the data frame have same integer by using fillna method

Tags: python, pandas

i have a an data_frame add some values using fill_na method  and convert in to a json

here is my data_frame

```
0                 home       Term    t1        t2     t3          t4   
1                 Yes          1   0.85      0.85   0.88         0.85   
2                 Yes          2   0.88      0.88  0.904         0.88   
3                 Yes          3+   0.91      0.91  0.928         0.91    
4                  No          1     1         1      1            1   
5                  No          2     1         1      1            1   
6                  No          3+     1         1      1            1
```

i need to manipulate this data_frame like this

```
0                 home       Term    t1        t2     t3          t4   
1                 Yes          1    0.85      0.85   0.88         0.85   
2                 Yes          2    0.88      0.88  0.904         0.88   
3                 Yes          3    0.91      0.91  0.928         0.91 
3                 Yes          4    0.91      0.91  0.928         0.91 
3                 Yes          5    0.91      0.91  0.928         0.91    
4                  No          1      1         1      1            1   
5                  No          2      1         1      1            1   
6                  No          3      1         1      1            1   
7                  No          3      1         1      1            1   
8                  No          4      1         1      1            1   
9                  No          5      1         1      1            1
```

i need to convert it in to a json like this

```
           {
```

"Yes": {
    "1": {
        "t1": 0.85,
        "t2": 0.85,
        "t3": 0.88,
        "t4": 0.85

```
},
"2": {
    "t1": 0.88,
    "t2": 0.88,
    "t3": 0.904,
    "t4": 0.88

},
"3": {
    "t1": 0.91,
    "t2": 0.91,
    "t3": 0.928,
    "t4": 0.91

},
"4": {
     "t1": 0.91,
    "t2": 0.91,
    "t3": 0.928,
    "t4": 0.91
},
"5": {
    "t1": 0.91,
    "t2": 0.91,
    "t3": 0.928,
    "t4": 0.91
```

} } ,

"No": {
    "1": {
        "t1": 1,
        "t2": 1,
        "t3": 1,
        "t4": 1

```
},
"2": {
    "P1": 1,
    "P5": 1,
    "P7": 1,
    "P10": 1,
    "P20": 0
},
"3": {
    "t1": 1,
    "t2": 1,
    "t3": 1,
    "t4": 1
},
"4": {
    "t1": 1,
    "t2": 1,
    "t3": 1,
    "t4": 1
},
"5": {
   "t1": 1,
    "t2": 1,
    "t3": 1,
    "t4": 1
```

}}}

Comment: How do you decide the last value of `Term` to 5? and why did `home == 'No'` get duplicates?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Also what is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: Is the last line of each Term always '3+', and do you always need to extend it to 5, or can the numbers change?

Comment: i need to pass any_ max value some for example 50 it should increment 1 from 3 like 4 5 6 and it should fill the 3+ values in all t1 and t2 t3  t4 and home as same as 3+ values

Comment: @kiran is it always 3? or anything that ends with '+' needs to be extended

Comment: @chris it is anything ends with '+'

Comment: and a cell ending with `+` will always be unique and at last, i.e. no multiple cells with `+`?

Comment: @chris yes chris but i do have '+' for  'No' also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, replace `N+` with `[N, N+1, ..., any_max_value]` and do `explode`:

```
any_max_value = 6
df['Term'] = [i if not str(i).endswith('+') else list(range(int(i[:-1]), any_max_value+1)) for i in df['Term']]
```

After replacement:

```
   0 home          Term    t1    t2     t3    t4
0  1  Yes             1  0.85  0.85  0.880  0.85
1  2  Yes             2  0.88  0.88  0.904  0.88
2  3  Yes  [3, 4, 5, 6]  0.91  0.91  0.928  0.91
3  4   No             1  1.00  1.00  1.000  1.00
4  5   No             2  1.00  1.00  1.000  1.00
5  6   No  [3, 4, 5, 6]  1.00  1.00  1.000  1.00
```

Then `pandas.DataFrame.explode`:

```
new_df = df.explode('Term').reset_index(drop=True)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
    0 home Term    t1    t2     t3    t4
0   1  Yes    1  0.85  0.85  0.880  0.85
1   2  Yes    2  0.88  0.88  0.904  0.88
2   3  Yes    3  0.91  0.91  0.928  0.91
3   3  Yes    4  0.91  0.91  0.928  0.91
4   3  Yes    5  0.91  0.91  0.928  0.91
5   3  Yes    6  0.91  0.91  0.928  0.91
6   4   No    1  1.00  1.00  1.000  1.00
7   5   No    2  1.00  1.00  1.000  1.00
8   6   No    3  1.00  1.00  1.000  1.00
9   6   No    4  1.00  1.00  1.000  1.00
10  6   No    5  1.00  1.00  1.000  1.00
11  6   No    6  1.00  1.00  1.000  1.00
```

Then finally do jsonify:

```
j = {k: d.drop('home', 1).set_index('Term').to_dict(orient='index') for k, d in new_df.groupby('home')}

import json
print(json.dumps(j, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "No": {
        "2": {
            "t1": 1.0,
            "t2": 1.0,
            "t3": 1.0,
            "t4": 1.0
        },
        "3": {
            "t1": 1.0,
            "t2": 1.0,
            "t3": 1.0,
            "t4": 1.0
        },
        "4": {
            "t1": 1.0,
            "t2": 1.0,
            "t3": 1.0,
            "t4": 1.0
        },
        "5": {
            "t1": 1.0,
            "t2": 1.0,
            "t3": 1.0,
            "t4": 1.0
        },
        "6": {
            "t1": 1.0,
            "t2": 1.0,
            "t3": 1.0,
            "t4": 1.0
        },
        "1": {
            "t1": 1.0,
            "t2": 1.0,
            "t3": 1.0,
            "t4": 1.0
        }
    },
    "Yes": {
        "2": {
            "t1": 0.88,
            "t2": 0.88,
            "t3": 0.904,
            "t4": 0.88
        },
        "3": {
            "t1": 0.91,
            "t2": 0.91,
            "t3": 0.9279999999999999,
            "t4": 0.91
        },
        "4": {
            "t1": 0.91,
            "t2": 0.91,
            "t3": 0.9279999999999999,
            "t4": 0.91
        },
        "5": {
            "t1": 0.91,
            "t2": 0.91,
            "t3": 0.9279999999999999,
            "t4": 0.91
        },
        "6": {
            "t1": 0.91,
            "t2": 0.91,
            "t3": 0.9279999999999999,
            "t4": 0.91
        },
        "1": {
            "t1": 0.85,
            "t2": 0.85,
            "t3": 0.88,
            "t4": 0.85
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: explode is only available starting in pandas 0.25.

Comment: @chris i need json_format  i mentioned in the above question